# Why does the unitary evolution of an operator involve a commutator with the Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, commutator, lie-algebra, unitarity

The equation for the unitary evolution of an operator $\hat{A}$ is given (as far as I understand) as $$\frac{\partial\hat{A}}{\partial t}=\frac{i}{\hbar}[\hat{H},\hat{A}].\quad\mbox(1)$$

It seems that $(1)$ is related to the Baker-Campbell-Haussdorf via a lemma which is written as follows: $$\mbox{Ad}_{e^X}Y=e^{\mbox{ad}_X}Y=e^XYe^{-X}=Y+[X,Y]+\frac{1}{2!}[X,[X,Y]]+\frac{1}{3!}[[X,[X,[X,Y]]]+...\quad (2)$$

I notice that e.g. $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}\big(e^{\lambda \hat{H}}\hat{A}e^{-\lambda \hat{H}}\big)\bigg|_{\lambda=0}=[\hat{H},\hat{A}].$$

This makes $(1)$ look like an infinitesimal change in $t$ on the left-hand side, and some sort of infinitesimal Lie group action of $\hat{H}$ on the right.

Is this interpretation correct?

Any explanations, especially good texts to consult, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Compare with the classical evolution $dA/dt = \{A,H\}$ where the right hand side is the classical Poisson bracket... and yes your interpretation is correct.

Comment: Thanks very much! One last thing: Above, can I just let $\lambda=t$? I think the answer is yes but I'd like a sanity check if possible!

Comment: Yes, you can name the parameter along the Lie flow anything you like. For the Hamiltonian, $t$ is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. It seemed fine mathematically, but it's the interpretation of this stuff I'm struggling with more. What I'm trying to do right now is be really clear, so although it's clear that the parameter can have any name it wants, I suppose my worry was that it would be somehow inconsistent with $(1)$ in some counter-intuitive way.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot for your help :)